# How to convert errai's: HTMLElement, Node into gwt widget?

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I've errai's widget of `HTMLElement` type. I would like to put into current page content from `org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation` class as follow:

`IsWidget widget = navigation.getContentPanel();`

`SimplePanel.add(IsWidget widget);`

but in errai in html templates java file HTMLElement is used.

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to this:

```
@Templated
@EntryPoint
public class App extends Composite {

    @Inject
    Navigation navigation;

    @Inject @DataField
    private SimplePanel content;

    @PostConstruct
    public void buildUI() {
        content.add(navigation.getContentPanel());
        RootPanel.get("rootPanel").add(this);
    }
}
```

Having a template that looks like this:

```
<div>
     <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```